# Trouble with COUNT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, PATIENT and VISIT. One with PatientID as the primary key and one with VisitID as the primary key. I need to select the first name and last name of the patients that have visited the hospital more than twice.

I have tried DISTINCT, a nested where clause, INNER JOIN, etc.

```
SELECT FirstName
     , LastName
     , PatientID
     , COUNT(*) AS total_visits 
  FROM VISIT 
 WHERE total_visits > 2;
```

It should just show the first and last name of the patients that have more than two occurrences in the VISIT table, but no matter how I rearrange the code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Gordon's answer and your comment I presume that PatientID in VISIT is a key to the PATIENT table.  So you will need to use an ´INNER JOIN´.  So your query looks something like this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, v.PatientID, COUNT(*) AS total_visits
FROM VISIT v
INNER JOIN PATIENT p ON p.PatientID = v.PatientID
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, v.PatientID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Note that AFAIK in Access you cannot use the alias name in the HAVING clause.  You need to repeat the COUNT(*) as is.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried this code exactly as displayed and it said PatientID could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause. Any idea what that may indicate?

Comment: Please see my Edit.  Just add v.  before the two PatientIDs, to specify that you are taking the value from VISIT.  You could equally well use p. All that matters is that one table is specified.

Answer (score 0):

You need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, PatientID, COUNT(*) AS total_visits
FROM VISIT
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, PatientID
HAVING total_visits > 2;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! But when I try this it asks for a parameter value on FirstName?

Comment: @Justin . . . That would suggest that `FirstName` is not really a column in your table.

Comment: If I look at the PATIENT table in Design View, I see FirstName, but that column isn't in the VISIT table.